# Space too small before word-starting subscripted symbol (LuaLaTeX only)

Tags: spacing, superscripts

I use `\textsuperscript` at the beginning of words and I have noticed that, as seen on the picture below, the space between the previous word and the superscripted symbol, **in case of shrinking**, becomes too small as compared to the other spaces.

The problem also arises if using `\raisebox` instead of `\textsuperscript`.

**EDIT**
`quark67` pointed out that the issue only occurs with `LuaLaTeX`, not with `XeLaTeX`.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 
 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
 \newfontfamily\djvs[BoldFont={* Bold}]{DejaVu Sans}
 
    
 \newcommand{\tech}{\textbf{\textsuperscript{\scalebox{0.85}{\djvs\char"2318}}}}
    
 \NewDocumentCommand{\techlexAUX}{mmm}{\tech\textit{#1}\IfNoValueF{#2}{\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{#2}}}}\IfNoValueF{#3}{ `#3'}}
 \NewDocumentCommand{\techlex}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}{\techlexAUX#1}
 
 \begin{document}
    I'm trying \techlex{arbre,n,tree}.\vspace{1ex}
    
    Similarly, if \techlex{attirement,n,attracting} is essentially found under the affective sense, it nonetheless allows writers to play with the ambiguity between a literal and a figurative interpretation, implying here again a neutral primary meaning inherited from the verb, waiting for further interpretation.
 \end{document}
```

[image]

**Now with XeLaTeX (no problem):**
[image]

**Bigger symbol, other letter than *f*, and negative \hspace (back to Lua)**

```
\newfontfamily\symbola{Symbola}[FakeBold=0.5]
\newcommand{\book}{\textsuperscript{\scalebox{1.2}{\symbola\char"1F4D6}}}
```

[image]

With XeLaTeX, the book symbol still has the spacing issue.

[image]

With LuaLaTeX:

[image]

Comment: You don't say if you compile with **lualatex** or **xelatex**, but when your code is compiled with **xelatex** the spaces are equals (not a tiny space as in red circle). With **lualatex**, it's as in your picture. I have just a warning (with the 2 engines) because the Times New Roman in small caps isn't available. I cannot test with your edited code, with the book (`\super`: undefined command). And I don't have the Symbola font.

Comment: basically lualatex doesn't an italic correction for an upright f (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=63038746#63038746). You could make a feature request in the luaotfload repo.

Comment: @Ulrike Here the example happens to involve an f but this is irrelevant, it happens regardless of the preceding letter. I changed it into a z in the other picture.

Comment: I don't have the symbola font and can't check the book symbol, with your example with deja vu the z is not a problem.

Comment: @Ulrike The issue arises with any symbol. You need to type the whole line so that the glue is shrinked. The problem occurs on both my desktop PC and my laptop and I have the latest miktex and Times versions. The difference is small, if you compile with XeLaTeX you can see what the right space should look like. With a bigger symbol such as the book, it's more salient.

Comment: @Ulrike I'm surprised, but with the book, XeLaTeX does not improve the space. See the new picture in OP.

Comment: I'm not surprised, with the `f` you have a problem with the italic correction (which is different in lualatex and xelatex), but with the `z` you get the normal spacing between chars, and obviously your book symbol protrudes to the left.

Answer (score 5):

The `\textsuperscript` command has nothing to do with the issue. The letter ‘f’ in Times New Roman protrudes a lot right of its bounding box:

[image]

The picture for TeX Gyre Termes would be

[image]

Unfortunately, no italic correction is provided (maybe it can be added with LuaLaTeX, so instead of an `\hspace{...}` command you could type `\/`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[
  SmallCapsFont=TeX Gyre Termes,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]
\newfontfamily\djvs[BoldFont={* Bold}]{DejaVu Sans}

\newcommand{\tech}{%
  \textsuperscript{%
    \scalebox{0.85}{%
      \djvs\bfseries\symbol{"2318}%
    }%
  }%
}
    
\NewDocumentCommand{\techlexAUX}{mmm}{%
  \tech\hspace{-0.1em}%
  \textit{#1}%
  \IfNoValueF{#2}{\textsubscript{\upshape\scshape #2}}%
  \IfNoValueF{#3}{ `#3'}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\techlex}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}{\techlexAUX#1}
 
\begin{document}

I'm trying \techlex{arbre,n,tree}.

\bigskip
    
Similarly, if \techlex{attirement,n,attracting} 

Similarly, if\hspace{0.1em} \techlex{attirement,n,attracting} 

\end{document}
```

**Notes**

1. I streamlined the commands.
2. The `\kern` in the definition of `\tech` doesn't seem necessary.
3. The symbol should be nearer the italic word that follows, rather than farther.
4. I added support for small caps, since my version of Times New Roman hasn't them.
5. I changed `graphics` to `graphicx`: you don't want the 1993 version, do you?

[image]

Comment: I added another picture to show that even with for example a "z", and even with a negative hspace, the space is reduced with bigger symbols. This one is actually the one which I had a problem with.

Comment: It appears the problem only occurs with LuaLaTeX, with XeLaTeX the result is perfect. So there is more than the "f" after all. So strange...

Comment: @VincentKrebs I can't reproduce your `z` example - can you post the exact code you used?

Comment: @VincentKrebs I get the same effect with XeLaTeX. It's possible that, *on your machine*, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are choosing different versions of Times New Roman. On mine, the one provided by macOS is used with both engines `/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Times New Roman.ttf`

Comment: @Cicada I just used `\book` instead of `\tech` and added a negative `\hspace` as `egreg` suggested. But never mind, you can use any symbol, the example was essentially meant as an illustration to show that the issue is not only *f* and that the negative `\hspace` can give unsatisfying results with some symbols.

Comment: @Cicada Even with a ° or † this is a pain. On the specific line of my real document, with the shrinking the space I get is so small that I can't even see it. I was forced to add a kern0.15em. This problem is bad. With XeLaTeX it's perfect.

Comment: @egreg I've no idea how to check. But I don't think I have two versions of Times New Roman. Could some other factor create this XeLaTeX difference on your system as compared to what `quark67` and I are observing? I wish there were a way to understand and flatten those asperities, since normally a LaTeX bit of code with a given engine, is supposed to produce the same result for everyone. After all, this is what LaTeX is about, isn't it. But yes, fonts are another parameter, I guess.

Comment: @VincentKrebs I still cannot reproduce the problem. And on my system (TL on Windows), both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX give the same result.

Comment: @VincentKrebs LuaLaTeX: the fonts used are listed in the log. XeLaTeX: do `fc-list` at the command prompt (i.e., list the fonts in the font-cache), and then scan through the output.

Comment: @Cicada When you say that you cannot reproduce it, do you mean that it's as good-looking with Lua as it is with XeLaTeX? Because I understood the opposite, ie. that `egreg` was implying that it was no better with Xetex. Inside which directory should I open the command window?

Comment: In XeLaTeX command prompt I got C:/Windows/Fonts/timesi.ttf: Times New Roman:style=Italic -----------
In Lua log I got:<C:/Windows/Fonts/timesi.ttf>
So, same font.
And:
`Package fontspec Info: Font family 'TimesNewRoman(0)' created for font 'Times New Roman' with options [Ligatures=TeX].`

Comment: `- 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:<->"TimesNewRoman/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;
+tlig;"`

Comment: @VincentKrebs Yes, all OK. I don't get the fontspec info message. Try `\setmainfont[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Times New Roman}`, or alternatively use LuaHBTeX.exe as the binary (it uses HarfBuzz font-shaping engine by default, like XeLaTeX does).

Comment: @Cicada Thanks for your help, `\setmainfont[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Times New Roman}` does nothing better, I will try LuaHBTeX

Comment: @VincentKrebs HarfBuzz has been part of lualatex for a while now. When I run `lualatex.exe`, the log shows `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022) `. Therefore, my fontspec.sty says: `\ProvidesExplPackage{fontspec}%
  {2022/01/15}{2.8a}{Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX}`. Sounds like your system is old and/or incomplete.

Comment: @Cicada No it's a fresh install. I get `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (MiKTeX 23.1) (format=lualatex 2023.2.24)  25 FEB 2023 05:21` ; `fontspec` is also 2.8a

Comment: My `timesi.ttf` file is Version 7.00.

Comment: @VincentKrebs What happens when you load the font explicitly by filename? (using `Path=c:/windows/fonts/,` and `Extension=.ttf` and so on - eg code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313766/fontspec-with-lualatex-using-arial-narrow-while-xelatex-is-correct))

Comment: Ok I did it with `\setmainfont{times}[
 Path = C:/Windows/Fonts/,
 Extension = .ttf,
 UprightFont = *,
 BoldFont = *bd,
 ItalicFont = *i,
 BoldItalicFont = *bi]` But it does not change anything, output is the same.

Comment: My `timesi` is version 7.03

Comment: @VincentKrebs I deleted the answer I previously posted. Apparently did not grasp the question.

Comment: @egreg And I guess it's impossible to automatize the space IF the precedent character is an "f" (what you were saying, that `\@IfPreviousChar` does not exist... Would be useful, though, 2nd time I would need it)

Answer (score 1):

I was told not to edit initial questions too much, so here is a little recap. Not much more than what `egreg` said, though.

In order to compensate for bad italic correction or large symbols, the best is to add a space inside the command, this way :

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 
 \newfontfamily\symbola{Symbola}[FakeBold=0.5]
 \newcommand{\book}{\textsuperscript{\scalebox{1.2}{\symbola\char"1F4D6}}}
 
 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
 \newfontfamily\djvs[BoldFont={* Bold}]{DejaVu Sans}
 
    
\newcommand{\tech}{\textbf{\textsuperscript{\scalebox{0.85}{\djvs\char"2318}}}}
    
\NewDocumentCommand{\techlexAUX}{mmm}{\hspace{0.05em}\tech\textit{#1}\IfNoValueF{#2}{\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{#2}}}}\IfNoValueF{#3}{ `#3'}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\techlex}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}{\techlexAUX#1}
 
\NewDocumentCommand{\booklexAUX}{mmm}{\hspace{0.05em}\book\textit{#1}\IfNoValueF{#2}{\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{#2}}}}\IfNoValueF{#3}{ `#3'}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\booklex}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}{\booklexAUX#1}
 
\begin{document}
    
Similarly, iz \techlex{attirement,n,attracting} is essentially found under the affective sense, it nonetheless allows writers to play with the ambiguity between a literal and a figurative interpretation, implying here again a neutral primary meaning inherited from the verb, waiting for further interpretation.
    
Similarly, if \techlex{attirement,n,attracting} is essentially found under the affective sense, it nonetheless allows writers to play with the ambiguity between a literal and a figurative interpretation, implying here again a neutral primary meaning inherited from the verb, waiting for further interpretation.
    
        
Similarly, iz \hspace{0.1em}\booklex{attirement,n,attracting} is essentially found under the affective sense, it nonetheless allows writers to play with the ambiguity between a literal and a figurative interpretation, implying here again a neutral primary meaning inherited from the verb, waiting for further interpretation.
        
Similarly, if \hspace{0.1em}\booklex{attirement,n,attracting} is essentially found under the affective sense, it nonetheless allows writers to play with the ambiguity between a literal and a figurative interpretation, implying here again a neutral primary meaning inherited from the verb, waiting for further interpretation.

\end{document}
```

[image]