# Italic Correction in Text Mode (LuaTeX)

Tags: italic-correction

I'm aware this may be related to that question I asked before:

[Space too small before word-starting subscripted symbol (LuaLaTeX only)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/676094/262813)

But since things have been moving lately, such as the recent introduction of `mathitalicsmode=2`, I thought I got nothing to lose asking.

Is there any way to automatically adjust the horizontal space after an italicized string, for example here?

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex


\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    
X\textsubscript{2}

\textit{X}\textsubscript{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Math mode has nothing to do with this. It's `\textit` that adds the italic correction. Use `\textit{X\nocorr}\textsubscript{2}`

Comment: @egreg sigh I should have remembered `\nocorr`, I guess you could add `\textsuperscript` to `\nocorrlist` if you have a lot of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LuaLaTeX has nothing to do with this. It's `\textit` that adds the italic correction based on a simple heuristic: if what follows appears in `\nocorrlist`, then the italic correction is not added.

One can also manually add `\nocorr` as the trailing token:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

X\textsubscript{2}

\textit{X}\textsubscript{2}

\textit{X\nocorr}\textsubscript{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add `\textsubscript` to the list, if you have several instances.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\nocorrlist{\textsubscript}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

X\textsubscript{2}

\textit{X}\textsubscript{2}

\textit{X\nocorr}\textsubscript{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I left `\nocorr`, just for comparison.